# Cell Locked / Unlocked based on Condition in Other Cell

Tags: vba, excel

Seek assistance for the following.
I'm trying to create a template to minimise user's data input therefore it is a protected sheet except for several cells where I'll unlock the cell to allow user to key-in their figure.

I'm trying to achieve the following.

Cell D3 will be conditioned based on the YES/NO drop down menu in cell C3.
If YES selected, user will be able to key-in their figure
If NO selected, cell will be locked and value from A3 will be taken

I believe this involves VBA; which brings to my next question:

Will VBA work for users using lower version of Excel?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO. *Will VBA work for users using lower version of Excel?* Please, specify what you consider lower version of Excel, but probably yes, it will work in mostly cases. Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and more good information at ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Tom I've tried following this but I am not sure how to change the code based on my conditions as I am quite an amateur with Excel
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35382249/lock-unlock-a-cell-using-conditional-formatting

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I'm using Excel 2016. Previously I've made an automated tax calculator based on salary range inputted by user. I used IF for that and some users complained that the tax amount was not displayed/auto computed even after I saved the file to lower version.

Comment: Normal Excel formulas should not cause any issue between different Excel versions. Anyways, about your question, I think the only way to do it is if you develop a code in VBA to lock/unlock D3 with your criteria.